# Angular material design mdToolbar and Ionic ion-nav-bar integration

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-material

I'm developing an app with Ionic and Angular Material.
Now I'm struggling to get Ionics back button to work when it is used under the `mdToolbar` directive of angular material.

You can see the problem here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/lfVVa4KAUkOFLOL1nQET

In index.html `<ion-nav-bar>` is located under the `<mdToolbar>` (line 59) tag and the back button and the title does not show up when navigating.

If the `<ion-nav-bar>` tag is listed anywhere else it works fine.

Any suggestions where the problem is and how to solve it?

---

While investigating this issue further it seems in ionic.bundle.js:48400 (`function getAssoctiatedNavBarCtrl()`) `navBarDelegate` is not initialized properly. But currently I have no idea why...

Comment: If u mix Ionic & angular-material, you will have lots of issues. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/29326397/3322160

Comment: @nitin Yes I see, there are some issues but it still has advantages (integrated build managment, cordova usage, ...). But if I only use angular-material, then how can I get the back-button functionality (also of the device back button) eg. from ui.router?

Comment: Ionic is made for mobile, it has its advantages. If u want material design, go for angular-material + cordova.   You can get back-button functionality inside angular-material by using $location service (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in material-design, then I recommend you to use Angular-material + Cordova.

[Here is yr plunk edited](http://plnkr.co/edit/EpF85EEdIUOEsKhqyya0?p=preview)

You will have to reorganize yr base layout :

```
<body layout="column" ng-controller="AppCtrl" md-swipe-right="openSidenav('left')" md-swipe-left="closeSidenav('left')">
  <md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')">
  </md-sidenav>

  <ion-nav-bar layout="column" class='bar-positive'>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <div class="row" style="min-height:400px">
   <div layout="column" class="relative" layout-fill="" role="main">
    <md-toolbar>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content flex="" md-scroll-y="">
        <ion-nav-view layout="column" layout-fill="" layout-padding="" class="ui-view-container"></ion-nav-view>
     </md-content>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
```