# What to use for Bootstrap and AngularJs multi-select?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Is there something that people default to when they need a multi-select drop down that will work in a bootstrap form without breaking the styling and accept angular attributes?

Found these, but am not sure either will work properly:
 1. http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/
 2. http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/configs-options

Upon checking docs twice - there seems nothing native in bootstrap and bootstrap-ui, but just wanted to double check.

Comment: check out https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select. It has a bootstrap theme too

Answer (score 1):

My tool of choice would be checkboxes using angular material: 
[angular material checkboxes](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.checkbox)
It is not bootstrap, but I prefer the presentation option on angular material to bootstrap, so have been slowly migrating away from bootstrap to using angular material instead.

Edit: Angular material is compatible with bootstrap. As you want a dropdown, this may be better: 
[angular material multiselect codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqwJwX)

```
 <md-select placeholder="State" ng-model="ctrl.userState" multiple="true">
        <md-option ng-repeat="state in ctrl.states" value="{{state.abbrev}}">{{state.abbrev}}</md-option>
 </md-select>
```

Comment: Good answer, ty, but I do need a drop down that works with bootstrap in this case.

Comment: I am not so sure Angular-material is compatible with bootstrap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313990/using-bootstrap-for-angular-and-material-design-for-angular-together