# How to extend angular-material components?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to apply angular-material in my recent project, but I am afraid that it will be very difficult to find other components which are not available currently.  Like treeview, date/time picker, carousel and so on...

How can I deal with these things? any opinions?

Comment: This isn't the right place to get opinions. That said you'll need to re-use an available component (e.g. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or build your own (or use a different framework)

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried to use Angular-Material in a site with an existing style, and found a number of issues that I wasn't able to resolve:
- Site UI was feeling very sluggish
- There was a paralax script that became extremely slow and lagged when there was a quick scroll. 
- Odd behavior with fonts when it loaded (when I re-sized the screen and back again it was working again) in chrome.

This became a real issue - for the most part it doesn't feel complete. I was really hoping for something like Material-UI, which appears to rely on React.

However, I have come across this https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html which appears to be suitable and works with bootstrap.

There's a really good answer : [Using Bootstrap for Angular and Material design for Angular together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313990/angularjs-bootstrap-for-angular-material-design-for-angular-together?rq=1) for some of the issues you will face when using Material with bootstrap.

Also, I tested on a mobile phone and the site was terrible (in performance), you'd never want to get site up with that type of performance.

Also, there's lumx if you want angularjs support (e.g directives etc...). My other issue with lumx and angularjs material is that swapping over libraries is not an easy task. I'm not sure whether this is the norm, and heading this way in the future - but I'm from the Jquery days where my markup remained consistent and I can activate features. However, both lumx and angularjs material require specific tags which means that swapping over libraries requires me to edit my mark-up.

Comment: exactly. Angular-Material transforms an i5 6gb computer on a athlon XP with 256megas of memory. It's not ready. And more, the final result is very different of android material (I program on android too).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe here is another view of using Angular Material.

I have been using Angular Material as the only web component for my work projects. Angular Material is still in beta version, and like you said, many components such as table, color picker, and sidenav are still missing. If you have to use those components in your projects and not able to implement yours, Angular Material may not be a right choice. Something like Angular-UI or Polymer is probably what you are looking for.

The reason we choose Angular Material at work rather than other nearly complete web component library/collection is because it is being very actively maintained. Currently there are 900+ open issues and lots of pull requests are still going on. For me, a complete version will be more guaranteed. Treeview, date/time/color picker, table these kinds of components are already in the open issues. Here you can search for it.
https://github.com/angular/material/issues

Currently we will find workaround or overwrite the material to solve problems. Or we will open issues if there is no solution. And again, it is still in beta version, you should decide whether you want to use it in your project. But you can definitely look at their available components to determine if Angular Material is a right choice for you.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I knew that material is very new with a lot missing parts and few third-party components unlike angular ui. But I still want to take the risk because: 1. I hope material team is quick enough to catch up. 2. I wish I will switch to angular2 + polymer later asap angular2 become rc, by doing that I wish it will be a lot smoth.