# Angular material design + bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-material2

Can someone explain to me, it is possible to use `material design` with `bootstrap` in Angular app with no issues?

I want to use `twitter-bootstrap`s grid system and `material design`s dialogues...

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: @FetraR.: there's no any problems?

Comment: Ya there is no problem we are using both in our project

Comment: I'm already using material design, but wasn't sure about `bootstrap`, thanks for response...

Comment: i guess you question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313990/using-bootstrap-for-angular-and-material-design-for-angular-together)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, as others have pointed out in the comments.

However, if you are only using bootstrap for its Grid system, you might find Material's `Grid List` may provide all you need:

Links:

- [Grid list overview](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview)
- [Grid list example](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples)