# Main differences between Angular Material + Bootstrap vs. MDbootstrap for Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, angular-material, mdbootstrap

I have some experience with Angular 1.x, and right now I am building a stack for couple of new projects.

- I want to have responsive grid, so I would like to use Bootstrap.
- I want to use Angular, so I am going with latest Angular
- I want to have material design... so I can choose https://material.angular.io/

... but I found https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/, which looks like some kind of combination of Bootstrap and Material Design which suppose to work as well with latest Angular.

I am confused and I am not sure what are main differences between those two approaches.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313990/using-bootstrap-for-angular-and-material-design-for-angular-together

Answer (score 4):

Material Angular allows you to use Flex Layout which gives you a responsive grid if you spend the time to learn it.

I've been using it for multiple projects and it is great.

Answer (score 3):

Taking into account all your 3 requirements mdbootstrap sounds like a perfect match. It's built with Bootstrap 4 and Angular 6.

It has definitely more components and features than Material Angular, though the extended version is paid. You can check the free version (MIT) and give it a try.