# How to combine Angular Material with a css framework (bootsrtap / semantic UI / materialize )

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, materialize

I'm working on an angular project where I heavily rely on some [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) components.

Additionally, I need to use a css framework for some other (basic) stuff which I can't find in angular material - grid, navigation bar, item positioning and so on. I started by including bootstrap, but I understood from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313990/using-bootstrap-for-angular-and-material-design-for-angular-together) that this is not recommended, well as inflating my bundle size? So what is?

Probably using [materialize-css](https://materializecss.com/) is the best, because it's the same design language. But is it included in `@angular/material`? I'm using a pre-built theme but is seems to contain only some of the classes. Do I add `materialize-css` as a separate dependency?

What's the best practice here?